# Generating sequential ids within a nested R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sequential

My R dataframe of teachers is organized by schoolid, with a variable number of teachers in every school. I want to generate a sequential id number for each teacher in my dataset.

Data looks like:

```
SCHOOLID  summer  
102349    1
102349    1
102349    1
102349    1
203456    1
203456    1
203456    1
345983    1
345983    1
345983    1
345983    1
345983    1
```

What I need to generate:

```
SCHOOLID  summer  teacher_id
102349    1      1
102349    1      2
102349    1      3
102349    1      4
203456    1      1
203456    1      2
203456    1      3
345983    1      1
345983    1      2
345983    1      3
345983    1      4
345983    1      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (assuming data frame is named mydf, change accordingly):

```
mydf$teacher_id <- ave( mydf$SCHOOLID, mydf$SCHOOLID, FUN=seq_along)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This seems to be a fairly frequent type of problem, so I wrote a function called `getanID` and included it in my "splitstackshape" package. Usage would be as follows:

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(mydf, "SCHOOLID")              ## If just one "ID"
getanID(mydf, c("SCHOOLID", "summer")) ## "ID" can be a vector too
```

---

#### Original answer

This is super easy with `ave` (and is definitely a duplicate question here on Stack Overflow).

The typical approach (if your `data.frame` were called "mydf") would be:

```
ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), mydf, FUN = seq_along)
#  [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

Replace the "mydf" with the actual columns that should be treated as your grouping columns. Here, I've just assumed that both columns should serve as the IDs.

---

In the above, I've grouped by the entire `data.frame`. However, if you only wanted to group by the first column, you would change the command to:

```
ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), mydf[1], FUN = seq_along)
```

(And, at this point, my answer and Greg's are pretty much the same, except for his use of `SCHOOLID` for aggregating instead of a dummy column of 1s.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this line, replacing mydf with the name of my dataframe, but I got an error message                                          Error: unexpected numeric constant in "ave(rep)1

Comment: @Suhas, are you paying attention to your brackets?

Comment: My apologies, I use Rstudio which automatically generates a closing bracket in the Rconsole and I overlooked that. The command below on my dataframe called myBy2 generates a vector of 1s of the same length as my dataframe (length of 6043)  >    myBy2$TEACHERID <- ave(rep(1,nrow(myBy2)),myBy2,FUN=seq_along)

Comment: @Suhas, that's why I mentioned "replace the 'mydf' with the actual columns that should be treated as your grouping columns" (which is what Greg has in his answer). In other words, if your grouping columns were column 2, 3, and 4, you would do something like `ave(rep(1, nrow(myBy2)), myBy2[c(2, 3, 4)], FUN = seq_along)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now ! I can either use the `rep` and `nrow` functions as you suggest, or just pass the arguments directly to `ave` and both  methods generate the identical result   >  myBy2$TEACHERID <- ave(rep(1,nrow(myBy2)),myBy2$SCHOOLID,FUN=seq_along)